# How to convert C uint64_t to Cgo consistently across OS?

Tags: c, go, cgo

I am using some C library form Go, using cgo to handle the conversion.

I have a C header file that looks like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   k uint64_t;
} params;
```

This structure is used from Go with code like:

```
package test

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L. -lmylib -lm -ldl
#include "mylib.h"
*/
import "C"
func NewParams(k uint64) Paramets {
  return Params{
    k:     C.ulonglong(k),
  }
}
```

The code compiles fine on OS X with Apple clang version 12.0.0, but fails on Linux with clang version 7.1.0, yielding the following error:

```
cannot use _Ctype_ulonglong(k) (type _Ctype_ulonglong) as type _Ctype_ulong in field value
```

If I change the call to `C.ulonglong` to `C.ulong`, it works fine on linux but then fails on OS X.

How can I ensure the same code works on both platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `go build -work` I was able to confirm the issue stems from differences in mapping:

- On the linux side, a C `unit64_t` gets mapped to a `C.ulong`
- On the Mac side, it gets mapped to `C.ulonglong`

Note that both `C.ulong` and `C.ulonglong` gets mapped to a go `uint64` but using the Go type directly and removing the `C.xxx(k)` conversion fails.

Solution is to use `C.uint64_t(k)` which makes it explicit the size of the type we are talking about. This is just fine because the C type *is* `uin64_t` anyways.

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me. I wish the main CGO documentation was more clear on this.